# "barplot: col" won't accept a vector of colors

Tags: r, colors, bar-chart

In R, I want to barplot a matrix `mat`

`A     B     C     D 
254  146    83    75`

and display the bars in different colors. However, when feeding
`barplot` with a colors vector, the result only shows the first color. An example:

`barplot (mat, col=c("blue","red","blue","red"))`

looks like this:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Seems to work for me, can you share the data object or check the type (`is(matrix)`)?

Comment: I get:

`> is(mat)
[1] "matrix"    "array"     "mMatrix"   "structure" "vector" `

Comment: I created it by:
`> mat<-matrix(data=NA,nrow=1,ncol=4,dimnames = list(c(1),c("A", "B", "C", "D")))`
`> mat[1,] <- c(254,146,83,75)`

Comment: The colors work fine if your argument is a (possibly named) vector. It seems odd that it does not work for a matrix, but just try the `c(254,...)`.

Comment: indeed, it works with a vector. However is there an idea why it wouldn't do so with a matrix?

Comment: Hmm it seems to be related to the indexing. Try `barplot (mat[1,], col=c("blue","red","blue","red"))`

Comment: `barplot` thinks it is doing a stacked barplot and the colors are recycled for each stacked bar. It is just that your stacks all have a single value.  Try `barplot (mat, col=c("blue","red","blue","red"), beside=TRUE)`

Comment: cool, that worked. thank you @timfaber and G5W.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to omit barplot to think it is doing a stacked barplot (with one single value per bar), I used:

```
barplot (mat, col=c("blue","red","blue","red"), beside=TRUE)
```

Thus, the colors are recycled over the bars and not over the stacks within each bar. Thank you @G5W for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me like both versions below:

## version1:

```
mat <- data.frame(mat)

barplot(mat,col=c("blue","red","blue","red"))
```

## version2

```
mat <- c(254 , 146  ,  83 ,   75)

barplot(mat,col=c("blue","red","blue","red"))
```